# How to use aws amplify searchable to search multiple key of model?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am using amplify graphql api. Where I have an Item model with different attributes.
I am trying to create an autocomplete or autosuggest api with user-added input.

```
type Item @model
  @searchable
{
  id:  ID!
  name: String!
  description: String
  category: String
  fullAddress: String!
  street: String
  area: String
  district: String
  city: String
  state: String!
  zip: Int!
```

Right now I aam querying it like

```
query SearchEvent {
searchEvents(filter:{
    name: {
      ne: $query
    }
  }) {
    items {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

But this gives me only full word match to a particular key, like this example is match of name.

How do I query to get a response of any match or suggestions from any key of the item object?
For example, if my item name is `Laptop` and api query is `la` it should return the laptop item and other matching items name.
Likewise, if api query is `ala` it should return the `Alabama, Alaska` names including the item name matching with `ala` with a limit to 10 let's say.

Anyway is this possible? Any lead will eb helpful.